# How to use IF ELSE and IF NOT conditions in the same batch file?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

Using a Batch For backing up a directory (Chrome). I'm using the native Windows Schedule Task Manager to ping, run the file (working great). However, if I go to bed (forgetting to shut down Chrome), naturally I don't get a full backup.

Therefore, I added the `else if`, however if I do shut down Chrome, the file runs, but it's rather "Dirty". How can I add an "if not"? Do I nest it inside the `else if`?

Here's what I'm running, again it works (regardless of if Chrome is shut down or not), but not "clean". I would like to make it clean, i.e. by showing an error like "Chrome does not Exist".

```
IF EXIST CHROME COMMAND (
    set drive=C:
    echo ### Killing Chrome Task
    taskkill  /F /IM chrome.exe /T
    PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
)
ELSE (
    :: variables 
    set drive=E:\BrowserBackups\Chrome
    set folder=%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~10,4%_%RANDOM%
    set backupcmd=xcopy /C/E/H/I/R/K/Y
    echo ### Backing up directory...
    %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome"
                "%drive%\%folder%"
)
pause
```

Not sure where to put the "IF NOT EXISTS" command.

Comment: Can't you use Windows PowerShell?

Comment: What on earth is this? IF EXIST CHROME COMMAND  <-- What is that?  You have a filename called CHROME with no extension?  and you want to run a command if the file CHROME exists, and your command is called COMMAND. What is this?!

Comment: I don't think the `ELSE` you have works the way you think it does.  But the `ELSE` is what you're looking for now.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes you're right it should be ) ELSE (   <--- see if /?  So ELSE on the same line as the closing brace of the prior IF

Comment: @barlop: the command named `COMMAND` might be `COMMAND.COM`.  These days it should be invoked as `CMD`, but the old name is still there.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What barlop is trying to say is that the syntax for `if` is all wrong. Probably the OP read somewhere (or saw in `if /?`) that he should use `if [not] exist filename command`, and actually typed the word "command". Also, the usage of `if exist` itself is incorrect here, since chrome.exe will always exist if installed. What he needs to check is if it's currently *running* or not.

Answer (score 1):

Structure your batch file like this:

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find /c /i "chrome.exe">NUL
if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (
    echo Chrome is running!
    echo Kill it and then backup settings.
) else (
    echo Chrome is not running!
    echo Can backup settings now.
)
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the "backup settings" part should follow the end of the if-else, since it should execute in either case.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I guess... But going by the OP's comment that he would like a "clean" backup (i.e. when Chrome's not running), I figured the above would be best. Anyway, the important bit's the chrome.exe running-or-not check and proper if-else loop, rest can be modified by him as per his needs.